# Get total partition count in each Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to calculate the number of partitions in each of my broker. We have a muli-DC distributed architecture; and would like to get the partition count per broker for maintenance and admin tasks

This is what was suggested in one of the blogposts; and works fine and this is at cluster level; however I need a similar script for per broker

```
zookeeper="ZK_SERVER1:2181,ZK_SERVER2:2181,ZK_SERVER3:2181"
sum=0
for i in $(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper $zookeeper ); do count=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper $zookeeper --topic $i |grep Leader | wc -l); sum=`expr $sum + $count` ;  echo 'total partitions is ' $sum; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Partition count is exposed as a JMX Mbean.

Install some agent such as Prometheus JMX Exporter, Datadog, New Relic, etc. on each broker, then collect and aggregate that information, adding tags for DC for further grouping, as necessary

---

Otherwise, I don't see why you couldn't add another loop to your script for a list of different Zookeeper endpoints for each Kafka cluster.

You need to parse that output to find *per broker*

Comment: Thanks, We are still a bit away from implementing monitoring.
I was looking for some cli commands/scripts to do that.
Can you please elaborate a bit about "add another loop to your script for a list of different Zookeeper"
So say for a particular region have 3 ZK server and 6 brokers. What will the next loop look for? Just checking the Leader for each partition will not be enough, i will have to parse the replica for each partition and calculate the Sum? Any dummy code will be helpful

Comment: You said you had multiple Kafka clusters? so `for zk in "cluster1:2181" "cluster2:2181" ; do ...`... Note: use `--bootstrap-servers`, not deprecated Zookeeper flag. Or, do the same in Python, Go, Java, or whatever you're more comfortable with than bash. More specifically, look at example output from one topic, and then the ISR column will need to be split, then you'd build a Hashmap of broker ids to amount of partitions. Bash doesn't really have good support for dictionaries, though, so you could pipe out `<brokerId> 1` for each partition to get a running tally, then pipe into awk to aggregate

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Admin` interface, list the topics, describe their metadata (that should contain the hosting broker IDs), then describe the cluster and match the IDs.

This is more or less what `kafka-topics` does underneath with different commands, as it's just a wrapper for underlying Java application.